# Crash with Wininet

Tags: php, c++

I am playing around with HttpRequests using wininet.

I try to make a httpRequest to send data to a PHP file on my local Webserver. Although it sends, but it suffers a crash along the line. My C++ Code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

#define PAGE_NAME "order.php"

#pragma comment (lib, "wininet")


int main()
{
    char firstname[50] = "John";
    char lastname[50] = "Darwin";
    char tel[50] = "08098688603";
    char idnumber[50] = "99057151";

    char* data = (char*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, 4052, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    //lstrcpy(data, PAGE_NAME);
    lstrcat(data, PAGE_NAME);
    lstrcat(data, "?&firstname=%s");
    lstrcat(data, firstname);
    lstrcat(data, "&lastname=%s");
    lstrcat(data, lastname);
    lstrcat(data, "&tel=%s");
    lstrcat(data, tel);
    lstrcat(data, "&idnumber=%s");
    lstrcat(data, (char*)idnumber);

    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("Vox", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hSession == NULL)
        MessageBox(NULL, "Bad InternetOpen", "Error", MB_OK);

    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, "localhost", 80, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    if (hConnect == NULL)
        MessageBox(NULL, "Bad InternetConect", "Error", MB_OK);

    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST", PAGE_NAME, NULL, NULL, (const char**)"text/*", 0, 1);
    if (hRequest == NULL)
        MessageBox(NULL, "Bad OpenRequest", "Error", MB_OK);

    if (HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, "Content-Type: app1ication/x-www-form-urlencoded", strlen("Content-Type: app1ication/x-www-form-urlencoded"), data, strlen(data)) == NULL)
        MessageBox(NULL, "Bad SendRequest", "Error", MB_OK);

    else
        MessageBox(NULL, "Data transfer Complete", "Sent Info", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);

    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);



    return 0;
}
```

Although it sends correctly with the complete information to the php file, it crashes in the line

```
 HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST", PAGE_NAME, NULL, NULL, (const char**)"text/*", 0, 1);
```

with the error

> Exception thrown at 0x7504712A (wininet.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x74786574.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

What could I be missing, is there anything I am not getting correctly?

Comment: Please do not include the error message as an image, but as text, this improves the searchability of this question.

Comment: Fixed it by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the array of accept types is not properly terminated with a `NULL`-pointer:

> A pointer to a null-terminated array of strings that indicates media types accepted by the client. Here is an example.
>
> `PCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T(“text/*”), NULL};`
>
> Failing to properly terminate the array with a NULL pointer will cause a crash.

[See here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: :) Thank You very Much. Indeed it was, i Corrected the information now and it sends the information with no Crash.  Thank you so much.